# Liberty can not serialize record type to json

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jsonb, websphere-liberty, open-liberty

I have this setup :

```
@Path("/client")
@Stateless
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
@Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
public class ClientResources {
    @EJB
    private ClientService clientService;

    @GET
    @Path("/get")
    public ResponseMessage getClient() {
        ClientRecordDTO resultDTO = new ClientRecordDTO(1L,"john","Maxim","23456789");
        return new ResponseMessage(resultDTO);
    }
}
```

And record :

```
import jakarta.json.bind.annotation.JsonbCreator;
import jakarta.json.bind.annotation.JsonbProperty;
import jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement
public record ClientRecordDTO(
        @JsonbProperty("id")
        Long id,

        @JsonbProperty("name")
        String name,

        @JsonbProperty("family")
        String family,

        @JsonbProperty("nationalCode")
        String nationalCode
) {
    @JsonbCreator
    public ClientRecordDTO(@JsonbProperty("name")
                           String name,

                           @JsonbProperty("family")
                           String family,

                           @JsonbProperty("nationalCode")
                           String nationalCode) {
        this(null, name, family, nationalCode);
    }
}
```

I can not understand why liberty application server can not serialize record to json !
I also wrote custom `MessageBodyWriter` but does not work

```
@Provider
public class RecordWriter implements MessageBodyWriter<ResponseMessage> {
    private static final Jsonb jsonb = JsonbBuilder.create();
    @Override
    public boolean isWriteable(Class<?> type, Type genericType, Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeTo(ResponseMessage responseMessage, Class<?> type, Type genericType, Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType, MultivaluedMap<String, Object> httpHeaders, OutputStream entityStream) throws IOException, WebApplicationException {
        OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(entityStream);
        writer.write(jsonb.toJson(responseMessage));
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();
    }
}
```

The interesting point is, I added eclipse yasson to pom.xml and try to serialize object.

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>org.eclipse</groupId>
     <artifactId>yasson</artifactId>
     <version>3.0.0</version>
     <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

that work without any problem :

```
import jakarta.json.bind.Jsonb;
import jakarta.json.bind.JsonbBuilder;
public class JsonTest {
    private static final Jsonb jsonb = JsonbBuilder.create();
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    ClientRecordDTO resultDTO = new ClientRecordDTO(1L,"john","Maxim","23456789");
        System.out.println(jsonb.toJson(dto));
    }
}
```

but liberty application server returned empty json block `{}` !
Actually i want to use record as DTO objects . there is any way to fix this problem ?

**UPDATE :**
this is server.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<server description="Tutorial server">
    <featureManager>
        <feature>managedBeans-2.0</feature>
        <feature>enterpriseBeansHome-4.0</feature>
        <feature>mpOpenAPI-3.0</feature>
        <feature>cdi-3.0</feature>
        <feature>concurrent-2.0</feature>
        <feature>enterpriseBeansLite-4.0</feature>
        <feature>restfulWS-3.0</feature>
        <feature>servlet-5.0</feature>
        <feature>json-1.0</feature>
        <feature>jsonb-2.0</feature>
        <feature>jsonp-2.0</feature>
        <feature>persistence-3.0</feature>
        <feature>beanValidation-3.0</feature>
    </featureManager>

    <library id="project-libs">
        <fileset dir="${server.config.dir}/lib/global/" includes="*.jar"/>
    </library>

    <dataSource jndiName="jdbc/jta-datasource" transactional="true">
        <jdbcDriver id="database-driver" libraryRef="project-libs"/>
        <properties databaseName="${database.name}" serverName="${database.hostname}" portNumber="${database.port}"
                    user="${database.username}" password="${database.password}"/>
    </dataSource>


    <basicRegistry id="basic" realm="BasicRealm"/>
    <httpSession securityIntegrationEnabled="false"/>
    <httpEndpoint id="defaultHttpEndpoint" host="${default.hostname}" httpPort="${default.http.port}"
                  httpsPort="${default.https.port}">
        <httpOptions http2="enabled"/>
    </httpEndpoint>
    <webContainer disableXPoweredBy="true"/>
    <applicationManager autoExpand="true"/>
    <applicationMonitor updateTrigger="mbean"/>
</server>
```

Comment: What Liberty features do you have active (configured in your server.xml file)?

Comment: OK, this is a current limitation.  Seems we already have an issue tracking:  https://github.com/OpenLiberty/open-liberty/issues/19698.  Open Liberty does use Yasson and since, as you noted, there seems to be now Yasson versions with support for records, it would appear to be just a matter of integrating an updated Yasson version within Open Liberty.